# Sorting using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sorting

I have to ask you question about sorting using hibernate, because I absolutely don't know how to resolve my problem, because right now I am on the project, which has been implemented with lot of problems and right know I am standing on one of them.

I have these three model classes.

First one is Document, second one is CustomProperty and the LastOne is CustomPropertyDefinition.

```
@Indexed
@Table(name = "documents")
@EntityListeners({ AuditingEntityListener.class })
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "isLogicallyDeleted", "textContent", })
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", length = 40)
    private String id;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "mimetype", nullable = false)
    private String mimetype;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "creator")
    private String creator;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created")
    private Date created;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "modifier")
    private String modifier;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "modified")
    private Date modified;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "folder_id", length = 40)
    private String folderId;

    @Column(name = "Ordering")
    private Date ordering;

    @Column(name = "definition_id", length = 40)
    private String definitionId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentDocument", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<CustomProperty> customProperties = new HashSet<CustomProperty>();
```

Custom Property :

```
   @Indexed
   @Table(name = "custom_properties")
   @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "stringValue")
   public class CustomProperty {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", length = 40)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "definition_id", nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String definitionId;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "value")
    private String stringValue;
    
    @Transient
    private String title;

    @Transient
    private Object value;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "document_id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = true)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Document parentDocument;
```

And CustomPropertyDefinition :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "custom_property_definitions")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "definitionsUsedIn" })
public class CustomPropertyDefinition {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", length = 40)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "property_type", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String propertyType;

    @Column(name = "symbolic_name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String symbolicName;

    @Column(name = "lower_bound")
    private String lowerBound;

    @Column(name = "upper_bound")
    private String upperBound;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "custom_property_definition_allowed_values", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @Column(name = "allowedValue")
    @OrderBy("allowedValue ASC")
    private Set<String> allowedValues;

    @Transient
    private Set<String> allowedValuesToAdd = new HashSet<String>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "customPropertyDefinitions")
    private Set<DocumentClassDefinition> definitionsUsedIn;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "custPropDefinitions")
    private Set<PropertyFolderStructure> propertyFolderStructure;
```

I am using pagination for returning the documents, but I need to have sorted attribute of Document " CustomProperty " by Attribute of "CustomPropertyDefinition " - > symbolicName . Do you have any idea how to sort it ?

Thank you very much! Every advice for me is great!

Comment: `customProperties` is a `Set` and a `Set` has no order.

Comment: I know that Set has no order, but I have saved it in the database, so i would like to know if hibernate offers some way how to sort object by its second child, or how to say it .

Comment: `CustomProperty` has no reference to `CustomPropertyDefinition`, how do you want to sort it then?

Comment: Sorry, it is my bad. Attribute DefinitionId is Id of CustomPropertyDefinition..@Smutje